# How do I convert the src.zip file to jar file?

Tags: java

Please any one give me the suggestion for this. I'm having the Xerces-J-source.zip file and I need to convert to Xerces-J-source.jar file.

Comment: Why? If you want to use it for an IDE, they usually also take zip files.

Comment: What do you mean by Convert Zip to Jar?

Comment: Do you just need the sources (if so, the zip should be fine as is)? Or do you actually need to compile them into classes?

Comment: **Why** do you need the **sources** in a `.jar` representation for?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Generally if your ZIP contains the class files (And not the sources):

Just rename the file, a `jar` is a `zip` file. But if you're aiming for a class to be launched with command `java -jar myProject.jar` you should create a [MANIFEST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifest_file) file containing the main-class and libraries to use in the classpath.

So in your case since you got the sources (Java file), you'll have to compile classes and create the JAR. Eclipse has an `Export as JAR` feature if you use it.

Comment: Yes, but depending on how you need to use the jar, not every zip file is also a jar file. There may need to be a certain folder structure or manifest entries. @Adalarsan: Where do you want to use the jar.

Comment: *This is technically a correct answer to the question*, **but I think the question is flawed**, if they want to actually use the code it has to be **compiled** and then bundled into a `.jar` file, otherwise it is just source code and useless.

Comment: OP mention `Xerces-J-source.zip` that means the zip contains java files not java classes.

Comment: @Crazenezz Right I didn't focus on the `source`. Well I let this answer as information.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson it all depends on what the asker really wants to do

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't make any sense. If you need Xerces-J the better is download the jars from the [website](http://www.apache.org/dist/xerces/j/).

If you want the get the jar form the source, you need to compile it, but there is no need when you can download it.