# .zip not converting into .jar properly

Tags: jar, zip, minecraft

When converting .zip files into .jar files by renaming them they always corrupt. I'm downloading the source code for a Minecraft mod and editing some of the .json files in it nothing much but when I change the . suffix from zip to jar the mod does not show up. Does anyone know a better way to convert a zip file of source code into a .jar?

Im not very experienced with these things as I just started playing Minecraft and wanted to make a cool mod for me and my friends.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert the src.zip file to jar file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11220680/how-do-i-convert-the-src-zip-file-to-jar-file)

Comment: Also, did you tried things like that: https://convertio.co/fr/zip-jar/